# How to perform split and join functions on Array in C?

Tags: c

How can I perform join and split functions on array elements in C?

For example, let's say I have two arrays:

```
int value[]=  {0,1,2,3};
int id[]  = {1,1,3,3};
// I want to join the elements of "value" array whoz value of "id" are same.
//In my case 0,1 elements from "value" array has the same "id" value that is 1,1
//and 2,3 from "value" has same "id" value 3,3. So it will join {01,23}
//And if i want to perform split function it will give me back{0,1,2,3}
```

I did the same thing in perl script but i am not sure how can I get this functionality in C?

Comment: I have no idea at all of what you are trying to achive. I think you maybe are confusing string values and integers in some way.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have built-in "dynamic" arrays like those of many higher-level languages.

You must allocate the needed storage yourself using `malloc()`, then copy the desired data element by element into the new array.

Also I can't quite understand the desired operations that you describe ... "Join elements of `value` whose value of `id` are the same" doesn't make sense.

Do you want to compute the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of the arrays? But they're clearly not sets, so that doesn't sound right either.

Comment: These are two parallel arrays.Let say value[0] and value[1] has the same integer value in id[0], and id[1] so i want to join these two elements in other array as a single element. same in the case of value[2], and value[3]

Comment: Ok lets think about a structure struc test{ value; id;} test test[4]; what i want i want to join all elements of value whoz id value is same.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you want:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int i,v;
  int ID_SIZE=7;
  int value[]={0,1,2,3,1,4, 7};
  int id[]=   {1,1,3,3,2,2,10};

  //Discover largest and smallest ids in order to allocate memory
  int min=0,max=0,length;
  for(i=1;i<ID_SIZE;++i){
    if(id[i]<id[min]) min=i;
    if(id[i]>id[max]) max=i;
  }
  //Replace ids with values
  min=id[min];
  max=id[max];
  length=max-min+1;

  int **unions;
  int *append;
  append=(int *)calloc(length,sizeof(int));

  for(i=0;i<length;++i)
    append[i]=-1;    //Initial insertion point for each id is at 0

  //Create 2D array unions[IDS HERE][VALUES HERE]
  unions=(int **)calloc(length,sizeof(int*));
  for(i=0;i<length;++i)
    unions[i]=(int *)calloc(ID_SIZE,sizeof(int));

  //Join arrays
  for(i=0;i<ID_SIZE;++i){
    printf("Inserting %d into %d at %d\n",value[i],id[i],append[id[i]-min]+1);
    unions[id[i]-min][++append[id[i]-min]]=value[i];
  }

  for(i=0;i<length;++i){
    if(append[i]>=0){
      printf("Id %d has: ",i+min);
      for(v=0;v<=append[id[i]-min];++v)
        printf("%d ",unions[i][v]);
      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It creates two dynamic arrays.

One array, called `append` keeps track of how many values have been found for each id.

The other array, called `unions` stores the result of the computation.

In the case of the input I define in the program, the following is returned:

```
Inserting 0 into 1 at 0
Inserting 1 into 1 at 1
Inserting 2 into 3 at 0
Inserting 3 into 3 at 1
Inserting 1 into 2 at 0
Inserting 4 into 2 at 1
Inserting 7 into 10 at 0
Id 1 has: 0 1 
Id 2 has: 1 4 
Id 3 has: 2 3 
Id 10 has: 7
```